# Apache Flink: Watermarks, Dropping Late Events, and Allowed Lateness

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, windowing

I am having trouble understanding the concept of watermarks and allowed lateness.

Following is an excerpt from the [mail archive|https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg08758.html] that talks about Watermarks but I have a couple of questions still. The following is the example quoted.:

> Assume you have a `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` with a 2 minute bound and a 10 minute tumbling window that starts at 12:00 and ends at 12:10:
>
> If you have the following stream sequence:
>
> ```
> 12:01, A
> 12:04, B
> WM, 12:02 // 12:04 - 2 minutes
> 12:02, C
> 12:08, D
> 12:14, E
> WM, 12:12
> 12:16, F
> WM, 12:14 // 12:16 - 2 minutes
> 12:09, G
> ```
>
> **no allowed lateness**
>
> The window operator forwards the logical time to 12:12 when it receives `<WM, 12:12>` and evaluates the window which contains `[A, B, C, D]` at this time and finally purges its state. `<12:09, G>` is later ignored.
>
> **allowed lateness of 3 minutes**
>
> The window operator evaluates the window when `<WM, 12:12>` is received, but its state is not purged yet. The state is purged when `<WM, 12:14>` is received (window fire time 12:10 + 3mins allowed lateness). `<12:09, G>` is again ignored.
>
> **allowed lateness of 5 minutes**
>
> The window operator evaluates the window when `<WM, 12:12>` is received, but its state is not purged yet. When `<12:09, G>` is received, the window is again evaluated but this time with `[A, B, C, D, G]` and an update is sent out. The state is purged when a watermark of >= 12:15 is received.

As I understand:

1. A watermark is supposed to tell that any element that arrives with an event timestamp less than that of the watermark will be dropped. So a watermark of 12:02 means that Flink has seen all that it had to see till event time 12:02. Any element having an event timesatamp lesser than this watermark e.g. 12:01 would be dropped.
2. The concept of Allowed lateness applies only after the last watermark that marks the end of a window

My questions based on the understanding:

1. How is message "12:02,C" being entertained considering Flink, with the previous watermark (WM, 12:02), has already said "*I have seen everything till event time 12:02*"?
2. I have tweaked the stream sequence and inserted another record 12:01,CCC at a point as shown below in bold in the stream sequence.

> If you have the following stream sequence:
>
> ```
> 12:01, A
> 12:04, B
> WM, 12:02 // 12:04 - 2 minutes
> 12:02, C
>  12:01, CCC // Inserted by Sheel
> 12:08, D
> 12:14, E
> WM, 12:12
> 12:16, F
> WM, 12:14 // 12:16 - 2 minutes
> 12:09, G
> ```

This is still in the 12:00-12:10 window but behind the watermark WM, 12:02. Lets say the allowed lateness is 5 mins. Will this record be accepted "somehow" bringing in the allowed lateness into picture or would this be dropped considering the watermark 12:02 has already crossed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Watermarks` control the lifetime of a window but not directly whether a record is dropped or not. When Flink's `WindowOperator` receives a new record, it will calculate the set of windows it falls into. If this set contains at least one active window, meaning that there is no watermark with a higher value than the window's end time + allowed lateness, the record will be assigned to this window and will become part of the window computation (even if the record's timestamp is lower than the last seen watermark). Hence, one could say that windows reduce the resolution of watermarks with respect to the individual records.

In your case, this means that both `C` and `CCC` will become part of the window `12:00 - 12:10` since the system hasn't seen a `Watermark` with >= `12:10`, yet.

Comment: Another way to think about Watermarks is that they trigger computations that have been scheduled for a specific time. Records can be added to a window as long as the window was not evaluated, i.e., until the watermark passed the window end time. By default the content of a window is deleted after it was evaluated (hence late events cannot be added to the result). With allowed lateness, the window content is maintained for a little longer and late events can be used to update the result.

Comment: Does the window still get triggered when lateness elapse, if there is no late element. Eg. Window ends at t, window triggers. The lateness expire at t+2 but no late element arrives between t and t+2, then does the window computation still get triggered or just the state is purged without any window computation. @FabianHueske

Comment: I think by default, window results are only updated when a late record is received. But this can by explicitly controlled with a custom trigger.